# Rails belongs_to_many

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations

I'm a beginner in Rails and I have a problem with `ActiveRecords` associations. 
I'm creating simple car rental service and I made the following associations:

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :rentals
  has_many :bookings
  has_many :cars, :through => :rentals
  has_many :cars, :through => :bookings
end

class Rental < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :client, dependent: :destroy
  has_one :car
end

class Booking < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :client, dependent: :destroy
  has_one :car
end
```

What I need is to have a car belonging to many bookings and rentals while every booking and rental can have only one car assigned.

```
class Car < ActiveRecord::Base
    # belongs_to_many :bookings
    # belongs_to_many :rentals
end
```

How should I do that?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

If a car can have many bookings/rentals, but a booking/rental can only have one car, you're looking at a classic `belongs_to`/`has_many` situation. It looks like you're being tripped up by the distinction between `belongs_to` and `has_one` -- it's not a grammatical one, but a matter of where the foreign key column is located in your database.

- `belongs_to`: "I am related to exactly one of these, and I have the foreign key."
- `has_one`: "I am related to exactly one of these, and it has the foreign key."
- `has_many`: "I am related to many of these, and they have the foreign key."

Note that `has_one` and `has_many` both imply there's a `belongs_to` on the other model, since that's the only option where "this" model has the foreign key. Note also that this means `has_one` should only be used when you have a one-to-one relationship, not a one-to-many.

Taking this into consideration, I would replace the `has_one :car` with `belongs_to :car` in both your Rental and Booking models, and place `has_many :bookings` and `has_many :rentals` in your Car model. Also ensure that your `rentals` and `bookings` tables have a `car_id` column; there should be no rental- or booking-related columns in your `cars` table.

Comment: That's what I figured out yesterday, but I needed a confirmation. Thanks for explaining it!

Comment: Is there a "I am related to many of these, and I have the foreign keys" relation? What is it? Thanks!

Comment: @Ziggy, there is no option that involves a model storing multiple foreign keys, since this isn't really possible using standard SQL column types. If you have a many-to-many relationship (e.g. posts have many tags, and tags have many posts), it should be represented by a third model (e.g. Tagging) in a [`has_many :through` configuration](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association).

Comment: plus one for a simple explanation - even useful to someone using a completely different programming language

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is a "belongs_to_many" in Rails, sort of. It's a little more work and you can't use generators with it. It's called a [polymorphic](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations) association.

Even though you could make a car have many bookings & rentals, you could associate the car by making it belong to a polymorph such as `rentable_vehicle`. Your code would look like this

```
class Car < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :rentable_vehicle, polymorphic: true
end

class Rental < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :client, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :cars, as: :rentable_vehicle
end

class Booking < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :client, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :cars, as: :rentable_vehicle
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do belongs_to_many. The closest you can really get is has_and_belongs_to_many, but I'm not sure that's what you want here - unless you can have multiple cars per rental/booking. Check out the [guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) for a full explanation.

I'd change it up like this:

```
class Rental < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :client, dependent: :destroy
  belongs_to :car
end

class Booking < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :client, dependent: :destroy
  belongs_to :car
end

class Car < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :bookings
  has_many :rentals
end
```

Also, I don't know how your rentals relate to bookings, but my immediate thought is that there should be some relationship between the two, because you probably can't have a rental without booking it, right?